# Export html table to word that have tinymce on one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, tinymce

I have a HTML view and want to export the content of table which has tinymce on it to Microsoft word or even Microsoft Excel.
but when I export it to word I get textarea in word file instead of just text of column.

Thanks in Advance.

My word file:
[image]

My HTML view:
[image]

```js
function export2Word(element) {

  var html, link, blob, url, css;

  css = (
    '<style>' +
    '@page WordSection1{size: 21cm 29.7cm;}' +
    'div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;}' +
    '</style>'
  );

  html = element.innerHTML;
  blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', css + html], {
    type: 'application/msword'
  });
  url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link = document.createElement('A');
  link.href = url;
  link.download = 'Document'; // default name without extension
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'Document.doc'); // IE10-11
  else link.click(); // other browsers
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <button onclick="export2Word(window.docx)">Export</button>

  <br>
  <div id="docx">
    <div class="WordSection1" dir="rtl">
      <table width="95%" border="1" align="center" style="text-align: center" id="testtable">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="width: 10%">شهرت دریور</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 10%">نوع واسطه</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 10%">نمبر پلیت</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 10%">نمبر پارچه عوارض</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 25%;height: 90%">تثبیت عوارض</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width: 10%">تاریخ تثبیت</td>
            <td rowspan="2">شماره حکم</td>
            <td rowspan="2">شماره صادر</td>
            <td rowspan="2">پرزه جات خریداری شده</td>
            <td rowspan="2">تعداد</td>
            <td rowspan="2">قیمت فی واحد</td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="text-wrap:inherit">قیمت عمومی</td>
            <td rowspan="2">تاریخ</td>
            <td rowspan="2">ملاحظات</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>اسم</td>
            <td>ولد</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($result as $a=>$row)
          <tr>
            <td id="">{{$row->driver_name}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->father_name}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->vehicle_type}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->plate_no}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->serial_number}}</td>
            <td><textarea class="checkkkkk" id="ddd{{$bbb}}">{{$row->description}}</textarea>
            </td>
            <td id="asdf{{$aaa}}">
              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $("#asdf" + {
                    {
                      $aaa
                    }
                  } + "").text(moment("{{$row->created_at}}").format('jYYYY/jM/jD'));
                });
              </script>
              {{$aaa++}}
            </td>
            <td id="">{{$row->order_number}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->export_number}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->buy_parts}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->quantity}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->per_item_price}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->total_price}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->export_date}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$row->remarks}}</td>
          </tr>

          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

or is there any javascript library that can do that even with tinymce

Answer (score 1):

```
Follow this instruction for export Doc with Excel file
http://localhost/tableToDoc.php?rType=1&fName=test
-Copy this code and see
- First of all create the table by Microsoft office then go to 'Preview in Web Browser' then Ctrl+u. Copy this source code and past your html page. you can change this source code.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="bn">
<?php 
        $repFor = $_GET['rType'];   
        $fileName = $_GET['fName'];
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        if($repFor == '1'){ // 2 = Export excel file
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".$fileName.".xls");
        }
        if($repFor == '2'){ // 3 = Export word file    
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".$fileName.".doc");    
        }
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
?>
<head>
    <title>HTML Table to xls and doc file export</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: landscape;
        }
        .tblBorder{
            border-top: 1px solid #000000; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; 
            border-left: 1px solid #000000; 
            border-right: none; 
            padding-top: 0.04in; 
            padding-bottom: 0.04in; 
            padding-left: 0.04in; 
            padding-right: 0in
        }
        .tblBorder2{
            border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: none; padding-top: 0in; padding-bottom: 0.04in; padding-left: 0.04in; padding-right: 0in
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr valign="top">
        <td rowspan="2" width="17%" class="tblBorder">
            <p align="center">Name</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="17%" class="tblBorder">
            <p align="center">Website</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="17%" class="tblBorder">
            <p align="center">Sub-Table</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" width="17%" class="tblBorder">
            <p align="center">Subject</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" width="33%" style="border: 1px solid #000000; padding: 0.04in">
            <p align="center">Group</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td width="17%" class="tblBorder2">
            <p align="center">Science</p>
        </td>
        <td width="17%" style="border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; padding-top: 0in; padding-bottom: 0.04in; padding-left: 0.04in; padding-right: 0.04in">
            <p align="center">Arts</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td width="17%" class="tblBorder2">
            Bulbul
        </td>
        <td width="17%" class="tblBorder2">
            bdprescription.com
        </td>
        <td width="17%" class="tblBorder2">
            <div>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tblBorder">Sub-Table</td>
                    <td class="tblBorder">Sub-Table</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tblBorder">Sub-Table</td>
                    <td class="tblBorder">Sub-Table</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td width="17%" class="tblBorder2">
            Match
        </td>
        <td width="17%" class="tblBorder2">
            Yes
        </td>
        <td width="17%" style="border-top: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; padding-top: 0in; padding-bottom: 0.04in; padding-left: 0.04in; padding-right: 0.04in">
            No
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but I want the reverse of what you say I want to export html table to word or excel with have tinymce on it

Comment: Welcome, If you set English font in every <td>abcd</td> then It would be helpful for me to understand actually what you say.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `direction:rtl` to the table and it will fix that inverse for you

```
  css =
"<style>" +
"@page WordSection1{size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;mso-page-orientation: landscape;}" +
"div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1; dir:rtl }" +
"   table {border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;direction:rtl;}" +

"</style>";
```